# How do you get more space on Live Mesh/Live Sync?

Tags: cloud, windows-live-mesh, onedrive, windows-live-sync

I'm looking into corporate data backs for my company's dealers. Each dealership will have data back up demands ranging from 100mb to 20gb. We are an entirely Microsoft solution so when I was asked to look into back ups, of course I would look to Microsoft.

Even if we have too buy this space, is there a way to get more space on Live Mesh/Live Sync (Live Mync hehe)?  The 5 gb that Mesh provides or the 2gb that Sync provides isn't enough for our larger dealerships.

The 25gb that SkyDrive provides is probably enough for now, but I don't know if it will be in the future. However, SkyDrive is not automatically synced. So it isn't a viable option anyway.

Comment: Super User is intended for computer hardware and software related questions.  Questions concerning "cloud services" such as Live Mesh and SkyDrive are considered off-topic.  Please see the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: I've had enough of my questions closed for being on the fringe of things to know not to argue with you. But you have to admit, live mesh and live sync are programs. skydrive I admit, is not. so i guess it makes sense to close this. but i must ask you now then. where would i ask this question? certainly not SO or SF. and if not SU then I'm stuck with no help. what's wrong with this picutre? aren't these sites supposed to be to help IT professionals and other people with computer problems?

Comment: I have no experience with Live Mesh/Sync/whatever, but since it's corporate data backup, I'd imagine people would have no problem with it over at SF.

Comment: @Narcolapser: ask it on http://webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: @heavyd What the heck are you talking about? This is clearly a software question.

Comment: @Senseful Live Mesh is not a web app, they would just close it as off-topic too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to get more space on Live Sync.

You could look at [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/), a similar thing, which has a free 2GB service but larger storage options for a fee.

For commercial backups, perhaps you should be using a more reliable (ie one which will guarantee the safety of your data - I haven't checked but I doubt that Live Sync will do that) service.